# Use CSS Grid to fit the red field into the red border in Grid Attack level 63

Tags: css, css-grid

I got stuck on [Coding Fantasy: Grid Attack](https://codingfantasy.com/games/css-grid-attack) level 63 for hours. I tried everything and nothing worked so far. The game provides no solutions, and I can’t skip the level. Does anyone know the solution please?

I need to fit the red land into the red border in the image below.

##### HTML

```html
<div id="field">
  <div class="greenLand"></div>
  <div class="redLand"></div>
  <div class="greenLand"></div>
  <div class="redLand"></div>
</div>
```

##### CSS

```css
#field {
  display: grid;
  gap:15px;
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 200px 1fr;
}
.redLand {
    
}
```

[image: Coding Fantasy: Grid Attack level 63]

Comment: I was curious about Coding Fantasy: Grid Attack, so I've had a go. I think there might be some bugs in it, though. I'm stuck on 47, even though my lands line up with the dotted lines, it's saying I'm incorrect. If you help me with 47, I'll keep going and help you with 63. Maybe I should have opted for the lower level of difficulty!

Comment: Have you tried `.redLand {place-self: top right}`?

Answer (score 2):

#field looks good but you need to add the correct width, height and justify-self to .redLand:

```
#field {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(2, 1fr) / 200px 1fr;
  gap: 15px;
}

.redLand {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  justify-self: end;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fact that setting width and height is necessary here. I missed this.